# javascript single quote issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I creating asp.net c# web application.
I have a linkButton (lnkDelete) on first column of each row  of gridview.
Also i am adding an attribute  dynamically to that link button inside "RowDataBound" event of GridView.
Like as follows :

```
  lnkDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to   delete this Product :" +
                    DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductName") + "')");
```

Now What i am trying to do is when user click that link button a   javascript confirm popup open up ,asking "Are you sure you want to delete this product".
Every thing work fine . But Problem occures when the name of the products comes with sngle quote.
Like : Product'One.
Syntax Error comes in ErrorConsole (javascript) when i click lnkDelete and error is : ( illegal character  )
I know the problem is with single quote.

Please suggest me what change required in my above code.
I hope i am clear.

Comment: Does your ProductName contain a single quote?  This looks OK to me.

Comment: Try using the `Replace` method to doublequote the quote - i.e., `DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductName").Replace("'","''")`

Comment: @Tim, I think you mean \\'. `DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductName").Replace("'","\\'")`

Comment: @AdamPlocher - You're correct.  I haven't done client-side JavaScript in a while and forgot the escape character.  Theory was good, implementation was poor :)

Comment: @Tim i tried it ,but still same error occurs.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the outputted HTML?  "View Source" from your browser.

Comment: Try John's answer below - he's using the correct escape character, and he's also calling `.ToString()` on `Eval` - which is necessary because Eval returns an Object, not a String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about adding `\` in the single quote?

```
DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductName").ToString.Replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: i tried your option also ,its works fine.But this give wrong product name on confirm pop when name of product contain backslash like : '\\Prd    .It give (Are you sure you want to delete this product : '\Prd) instead of '\\Prd

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Instead of `DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductName")`

You can use

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductName").ToString())`

Comment: Only thing is if you have a single quote `'` and use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, it will turn into a `&#39` if displayed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried escaping the string?

If you have a escaped string, you can unescaping with javascript.

```
lnkDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to  delete this Product :' + unescape(\'" + escapedString + "\'))");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the similar thing in one of my automated tools for Search project. Here is what you can try:

```
protected void grdKeywords_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton linkDeleteButton = e.Row.FindControl("lnkdel") as LinkButton;
            Label lblGridKeyword = e.Row.FindControl("lblGridKeyword") as Label;
            TextBox txtGridBox = e.Row.FindControl("txtGridKeyword") as TextBox;

            if (lblGridKeyword != null)
            {
                if (lblGridKeyword.Text.Contains("'"))
                {
                    lblGridKeyword.Text = lblGridKeyword.Text.Replace("'", "&#39;");

                }
            }

            if (txtGridBox != null)
            {
                if (txtGridBox.Text.Contains("'"))
                {
                    txtGridBox.Text = txtGridBox.Text.Replace("'", "`");
                }
            }

            if (txtGridBox == null)
                linkDeleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure about deleting keyword: " + lblGridKeyword.Text + " ?')");
            else if (lblGridKeyword == null)
                linkDeleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure about deleting keyword: " + txtGridBox.Text + " ?')");




        }
    }
```

**lblGridKeyword** is the label which holds the data that contains the single quote. I replaced that using ' at the time of RowDataBound. This worked for me.